# modifiy connection manager information from SSIS Catalog from sql

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Is there a way, to update the connection manager information from the ssis catalog after deploying with an sql code ?

I'd like to deploy the project without sensitive data first :

- exec catalog.deploy_project ..
- then add username and password to the SSIS Catalog Project via SQL...

Comment: Yes, you'll need to use project variables, and then configure the values of the variables on your instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way, to update the connection manager information from the
>   ssis catalog after deploying with an sql code ?

It is possible since all changed in SSISDB catalog are via stored procedure.

This is a SQL script generated by SSMS during connection string change:

```
DECLARE @var SQL_VARIANT
= N'Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=dbName;
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;';

EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_object_parameter_value] @object_type = 20,
                                                     @parameter_name = N'_ConnectionStringParam',
                                                     @object_name = N'ProjectName',
                                                     @folder_name = N'FolderName',
                                                     @project_name = N'ProjectName',
                                                     @value_type = V,
                                                     @parameter_value = @var;
```

References:

- [catalog.set_object_parameter_value (SSISDB Database)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-stored-procedures/catalog-set-object-parameter-value-ssisdb-database?view=sql-server-2017)
- [How can I automate setting SSIS Project Parameters in SSIS 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24310991/how-can-i-automate-setting-ssis-project-parameters-in-ssis-2012)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're asking how to change the username and password once a package is deployed, I assume you're already familiar with the SSIS Catalog, if not the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/catalog/ssis-catalog?view=sql-server-2017) outlines this further.  To set the username and passwords via T-SQL use environment variables, with the variable holding the password marked as sensitive.  The `SSISDB.CATALOG.SET_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_VALUE` stored procedure is used to update the values of environment variables, including those marked as sensitive, and can be used as follows.

- Start off by creating an environment.  To do this, right-click SSISDB and create a new folder.  Then in this folder, right-click and create a new environment.
- After this right-click the environment and select **Properties** then go to the **Variables** pane.  Create a string variable for both the username and password, with the variable storing the password set as **Sensitive**.
- Next, right click the package or project depending on the scope that the connection manager was defined in, and press *Configure* and go to the **References** page.  On this add the newly created environment with the **Add** button.
- Still in the properties window of the project/package, go to the **Parameters** page and then **Connection Managers** tab.  Find the connection manager that will use the environment variables, right-click the ellipsis on both the username and password properties, change the radio button to "Use Environment Variable", and choose the corresponding variables.
- Before executing the package, run the `SSISDB.CATALOG.SET_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_VALUE` stored procedure to update the environment variables.  An example of this follows.
- If this package is executed using T-SQL from a SQL Agent job or another method, linked the environment reference to it as done below.

**Example:**

```
DECLARE @usernameVar SQL_VARIANT = N'UsernameValue'
EXEC SSISDB.[CATALOG].SET_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_VALUE @variable_name=N'Username', 
@environment_name=N'Environment Name', @folder_name=N'Environment folder', @value=@usernameVar

DECLARE @passwordVar SQL_VARIANT = N'PasswordValue'
EXEC SSISDB.[CATALOG].SET_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_VALUE @variable_name=N'Password', 
@environment_name=N'Environment Name', @folder_name=N'Environment folder', @value=@passwordVar

--make sure environment mapped with @reference_id
DECLARE @execution_id bigint
EXEC SSISDB.[CATALOG].CREATE_EXECUTION @package_name=N'Package.dtsx', @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT, 
@folder_name=N'Project Folder', @project_name=N'PackageProject', @use32bitruntime=False, @reference_id=99

DECLARE @var0 smallint = 1
EXEC SSISDB.[CATALOG].SET_EXECUTION_PARAMETER_VALUE @execution_id,  @object_type=50, 
@parameter_name=N'LOGGING_LEVEL', @parameter_value=@var0 

--execute package
EXEC SSISDB.[CATALOG].START_EXECUTION @execution_id
```