# Pass parameters into SQL job running SSIS package dynamically

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, ssis, parameters, sql-agent-job

I have SQL Server Agent job, that is configured to run SSIS package from the Catalog. The job itself works well. SSIS package can accept a parameter, for example, USER.

I need to run this job from a Web Application, for this reason, I am running it via a batch script using SQLCMD + dbo.sp_start_job

Here is a script string

> ```
> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd.exe" -Q "execute msdb.dbo.sp_start_job  @job_name=N'Sync'"
> ```

This works.

Is there a way to pass a parameter to this script so when the job is run it accepts a parameter for SSIS package.

I know I can hard code a parameter into the SQL Job itself, but I need to be able to pass it dynamically?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: There might be a way to script this as you'd like, but if nothing comes along, one way to accomplish the same functionality would be to have the web app write the value or values to a table, then reconfigure the package to pick up what it needs from there.

Comment: As you migt have guessed by the name. the `SQL Server Agent Job` is something executed by the SQL Server Agent - so basically it does not have a user it can request parameters from... however, you can specify under which user / context the Steps within a job are executed. Anyways, you might want to try what Eric suggested and populate a table ehich is then considered by your packages. Or you modify your App in order to execute the packages directrly (not via Job) and pass the parameters there.

Comment: If you are not overriding the default parameter value through the agent job, you can change it with [catalog.set_object_parameter_value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55220918) before executing the job.

Comment: This actually worked!!! Wohoo!!